# Include a re-usable text block in query

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, reusability

I am looking for a solution to create a separate text-block (consisting of certain conditions) which I could create just once and later reference it inside a query:

Example:

```
Re-usable text-block (A1, B1, C1, D1 and G1 are actual column names):
-------------
WHERE

A1 > B1 and
B1 < C1 and
D1 > G1  
-------------
```

and here would be the SELECT command:

```
SELECT * FROM table 1

---- insert reference to the re-usable text block --- 

UNION 

SELECT * FROM table 2

---- insert reference to the re-usable text block --- 

UNION

SELECT * FROM table 3

---- insert reference to the re-usable text block --- 
   ;
```

I am using UNION command in between Select statements since I have 30+ tables from which I need to fetch data that corresponds to the same exact criteria defined in this re-usable text bock. If I need to make a change, it will only apply to this re-usable text block.

How can I design this so that I only need to make the change in one place, and not once for each query?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [Prepared Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)?

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for the pointer! I would be happy to accept this as an answer, but for that you would need to re-post your response via "Answer" mechanism.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Commented first because I didn't know if it was what you needed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here to solve your problem is a [Prepared Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

This allows you to create a query you want to run several times, while only changing something minimal, such as a column condition.

In your case, if you want to have a parameterized where clause, you could do something like this:

```
PREPARE stmnt FROM 'SELECT myColumns FROM myTable WHERE ?';
```

Then, you can set a variable to match what you want in the where clause, and EXECUTE the statement with the USING keyword:

```
SET @condition = 'a1 < b1';
EXECUTE stmnt USING @condition;
```

Note the use of the `?` in the prepared statement. This is the placeholder for where the parameter will go. If you have multiple question marks, you will need to have multiple parameters following `USING` and they replace the question marks in the order that you write them.